# ¿Por qué file_get_contents("php://input") devuelve un null?

Tags: php, json, webservice

Estoy realizando el ejemplo de la creacion de webservice.
En este metodo estoy eliminando un registro

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    var_dump($body);


    $retorno = meta::delete($body['idMeta']);


    if ($retorno) {
        print json_encode(array(
                'estado'    => '1',
                'mensaje'   => 'Eliminacion exitosa'
            ));
    }
    else
    {
        print json_encode(array(
                'estado'    => '2',
                'mensaje'   => 'Eliminacion fallida'
            ));
    }
}
```

cuando imprimo la variable `$body` realizando la prueba en postman enviando el parametro idMeta mediante post, esa variable devuelve NULL y se muestra el mensaje que se elimino el registro cuando en realidad no elimino nada.

```
NULL {"estado":"1","mensaje":"Eliminacion exitosa"}
```

si en cambio envió un valor definido, de esta forma si lo elimina

```
$retorno = meta::delete(4); //envio valor definido
```

Comment: únicamente estoy haciendo pruebas desde postman, para eliminar registros.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` esta activado?

Comment: ¿como se activa eso ?

Comment: al parecer ya lo tengo activado. Lo active en el archivo php.ini